# What's the minimal (and fastest) way to touch a big file just enough to change it's HASH?

Tags: powershell, file-management, zip

I have big files (*.iso*, *.mkv*, etc) for which I need to change the HASH, so that they are not detected in a potential DHT network during transfer.

One obvious way is to add them to a zip file and break that zip file in 2 volumes (tools like 7zip do this).
The problem with this approach is that it takes a long amount of time (and requires extra space to be available on the HDD).

***Could there be a quicker way ?***
Something like `cutting 1Byte away, storing it in a small additional file, and re-joining the files once transfer is done` would be enough.
Would something like this work significantly faster ?
Could it be achieved relatively quickly (eg: some tool, or a powershell script), without me having to write my own python tool for that ?

Thank you.

Comment: If you have a hex editor you could just change a single byte or even a bit at the start of the file.

Comment: Please explain what "DHT" is.

Comment: if your machine has enough memory to completely read the file in then you can use powershell to change one specific byte: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20935356/methods-to-hex-edit-binary-files-via-powershell

Comment: @r2d3 DHT = "Distributed Hash Table" network.

Comment: @Mokubai would that work **significantly** faster ?  
Or in order to _change a single byte_ I need to basically open the entire file content and then save it all ?

Comment: Be aware that in most DHT deployments files are split in "chunks" with each chunk having its own hash. Modifying 1 byte would just change the hash for the 1 chunk with the modification and the overall hash of the entire file. Chunk hashes for other chunks of the file will not change. This may or may not be what you are after.

Comment: @Tonny that's a 'damn good point. That is indeed *not* what I'm after, as I don't want parts of the file to be discoverable based on their initial hashes... 

So I guess I'm stuck with zipping. I'll keep monitoring to see if the `store` mode of 7zip does the trick, or else I'm gonna have to *really* re-zip the stuff. Oh well...   
But thanks for the good remark!

Comment: @Serban 7zip store (or any other archiver with a store option, TAR comes to mind) should do the trick . Because a header is added in front of the file (and possibly a trailer at the end) all bytes move a certain offset "upwards"  in the file which will change ALL hashes. Tar in particular can be piped which may (depending on your use-case) make it possible to avoid having to read/write the entire archive to/from disk.

Comment: @Tonny indeed, if I could append some bytes **at the beginnig** of the file, then I could still achieve my purpose.  So the question is: **can I do something like that *without having to read/write the entire file content*** ?

Comment: @Serban Without reading/writing the entire file is in general not possible (but pipes may help to keep the amount of disk-IO to a minimum). With low-level programming and in-depth knowledge of the internals of the filesytem it is in theory possible to allocate a 1 filesystem sector sized random file and then merge that file with the original big file without reading/writing anything to the large file, just updating the filesystems internal administration. Very tricky to do and requiring admin/root access to the filesystem. And if you do it wrong you messed up the filesystem. Scary business.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In powershell, you can easily append data to a file. This changes the hash without loading the entire file into memory:

```sh
# check hash at start:
$file = .\BigFile.iso
(Get-FileHash $file).Hash
C95B3F05EB8641A483A2218F4D0D43540BFEB1CD3D55B87FF34158FF5417904B

# append three characters to file
'foo' >> $file

# OR specify the encoding to make it easier to remove later [recommended]:
'foo' | Out-File -Append $file -Encoding utf8 -NoNewline

# verify hash changed
(Get-FileHash $file).Hash
46E31A77CC3D0271061D7E54A35A6715AC263FDBCE1DF9F1BC69578A6AFB8686
```

Removing the last few bytes can also be done without re-writing the whole thing, but you do need to know exactly how much to trim. `foo` in UTF8 is 3 bytes, so:

```
# undo by trimming the last 3 bytes off the file
$stream = [IO.File]::OpenWrite($file)
$stream.SetLength($stream.Length - 3)
$stream.Close()
$stream.Dispose()

# verify hash is fixed:
(Get-FileHash $file).Hash
C95B3F05EB8641A483A2218F4D0D43540BFEB1CD3D55B87FF34158FF5417904B
```

Comment: you actually tested this ? what I see is real _before and after_ hash ?  
So appending `foo` like that won't break a binary file ?

Comment: @Serban yes, tested in PS 5.1. Of course, the file may not be usable until you remove the appended bytes (like if you had split the file in two). But after removing the bytes, the file will be identical to pre-append. You can look at the last few bytes with `gc $file -Encoding Byte -Tail 10`. `foo` shows as `102,111,111`. NOTE: in later PS versions, you must use `Get-Content $file -AsByteStream -Tail 10` instead.

Comment: I'll give this a try. If it works, it's perfect for my needs :)

Answer (score 0):

You can save and run following, to toggle first two bytes of a file.
When ran first, the file's header itself would seem like a garbage data file.
Running it second time, would revert it to original state.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
"""
Toggle the first & second bytes.
Syntax: python <py-file> filename
"""


import sys


def flip_first_bit(filename):
    with open(filename, "r+b") as fp:
        fp.seek(1, 0)
        byte_one = fp.read(1)
        byte_two = fp.read(1)
        fp.seek(-2, 1)
        fp.write(byte_two)
        fp.write(byte_one)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    filename = sys.argv[1]
    flip_first_bit(filename)
```