# Efficiently Add and Remove Bytes at the Start of a Large File

Tags: windows, powershell, filesystems

This is my 2nd attempt, after I got some answers to [an initial question](https://superuser.com/questions/1815996/whats-the-minimal-and-fastest-way-to-touch-a-big-file-just-enough-to-change-i) and then realized what I **really** need...

I have very big files (*.iso, *.mkv) which I need to alter by adding a fixed number of bytes **at the beginning of the file**. Obviously I would need to also reverse the transformation.

I'm wondering if there is a time-efficient way to do this, so that the entire content of the big file does not actually get read/written; instead somehow just the beginning bytes of the file are altered.

I need to do this in windows, preferably without having to write a python tool; a *PowerShell* script would work fine.

Is this possible ?

Comment: In terms of "*so that the entire content of the big file does not actually get read/written*" sounds tricky including memory only read/writes, not sure if PowerShell can do this. If there was a way to create a new file with the additional bytes and then append the content of the original file to it, sounds logical though if that is possible.

Comment: I am with @VomitIT-ChunkyMessStyle on this.  The sort of manipulation you are asking for requires direct file system access and an understanding of the file system and how to manipulate it.  ChunkyMessStyle mentions APPENDING content isn't quite right.. you want to PREPEND data.  Where would those initial bytes GO and how would they get linked in at the beginning of the file record cluster/chain?  The fact that you mention python and pwrshell tell me that this is probably out of reach for you.  Direct access to the FS is the only way to get it.  Mucking the FS directly might make this possble.

Comment: A file pointer points at an initial cluster of bytes, that cluster points at the next cluster of bytes etc etc.  You would need to be able to manipulate the initial file pointer to point at your new bytes and in turn, leave the other bytes alone and change the last chain of NEW bytes in your chain at the initial set.

Comment: Yes, prepend additional bytes is what I meant, my apologies. I just tested with small txt file and it works but using `[System.IO.File]::ReadAllBytes($File);`, `[System.IO.File]::WriteAllBytes($combinedFile, $combinedContent)` and a rename command but still reads and writes. That is correct, the additional bytes you want to add to the beginning of the original iso, you would prepend it—I forgot to me more non-human/alien for the day.... buzz out!! Good luck with this. Prepend additional bytes to original or append original to the additional bytes file..... Bzz